# How to Arrange multiple Group Headers correctly?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want to create this kind of Form
[Form Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN959.png)
but Im having a hard time on doing it due to lack of knowledge in crystal report
and this is the outcome that I created [Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sEL4.png)

I use multiple group header to create my form, and on the Group header1 I create GH1a to GH1c, on the GH1c I used it for sub total and suppress on the last record so it will appear on the last column of GH1b, my problem now is the next Table where in the Group Header 2. I want to Display the GH2 on the last record of GH1 but it only show the last record of the GH1 in GH2.

sorry if my English is not correct. Can anyone help me?